# flutter: Is there a way to reuse a widget?

Tags: flutter, widget

I have two widgets which are basically the same, except their color. They are list tile in list view builder. There is a checking to show in grey or red. The only property to be changed is color. I know that there is copyWith() function, but it seems that cannot be used in this case.
How can I reuse the below widget?

```
Widget listTile = Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[300],  
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
              message.title),
          subtitle: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(message.name),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.alarm_on,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                  Text(message.time),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: You could just write your own widget and pass color as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function which takes the `color` as a parameter..and return your widget from that function..

Something like this..

```dart
customWidget( Color color){
return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[300],  
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
              message.title),
          subtitle: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(message.name),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.alarm_on,
                    //color: Colors.redAccent,
                    color: color,
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                  Text(message.time),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And whenever you want to use it..do it this way..

```
customWidget(Colors.red)
```

Hope it solves your issue..feel free to ask for clarifications :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it a variable, you can make it a method and then pass the color parameter to it.

```dart
Widget buildWidget(Color color) {
 return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,  // Use your color parameter here
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
              message.title),
          subtitle: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(message.name),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.alarm_on,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                  Text(message.time),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

*You can also pass along the message object you are using as a parameter to the function*

So your `ListView.builder` will look like:

```dart
ListView.builder(
   ..., // other properties
   itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildWidget(/*Your params here*/),
),
```